# Can/Should you use RIA's core domain service to perform services not related to entities?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services, ria

I am using WCF RIA services with silverlight.  Obviously I am using this primarily for retreival of entities from a datastore.  My question is, is it OK to define other methods not related to CRUD operations of entites within the domain context? For example, I could define

```
    [Invoke]
    public void SendEmail(String Message)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
```

The sendemail method would have nothing to do with the entities of my application.

Is this done?  Any downsides?  Should I just define standard WCF services instead?

Looking for opinions as I can't seem to find information one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is perfectly fine. If you are already using RIA, I do not see any downsides. To make things more organized you can create another DomainService and separate your CRUD work of your other methods.